# skipping incompatible C:\GTEST\gtest-1.7.0\lib/libtest.a when searching for -ltest

Tags: eclipse

Eclipseでgoogle testを使ってユニットテストをやろうと思っています。

http://programingstudy2013.blogspot.jp/2014/08/eclipse-cdt-googletest.html
を参考にセットアップを行い、ビルドしてみると下記のようなエラーが出てしまいます。

```
skipping incompatible C:\GTEST\gtest-1.7.0\lib/libtest.a when searching for -ltest
```

環境はwindows7 64bit。EclipseはPleiades All in OneのMarsを使っています。MinGWはEclipse付属のものをそのまま使っています。

原因と対策方法をご教示願います。

Answer (score 1):

自己解決しました。

上記エラーはlibtest.aが32bit版で出来ていることが原因のようです。いろいろ調べた結果、64bit版のMinGWを使ってビルドすることで解決できました！